# React does not re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, state

I have React class with sorting function (List) and React class for simple element (Elem). If sorting function started, it sort elements in the array in the state and re-render List, but remains the same, although array in state was changed. Code:

```
var Elem = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        var elem_name = this.props.name;
        return {
            name: elem_name
        }
    },
    render() {
        return <div>{this.state.name}</div>;
    }
});

var List = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            received: false,
            arr: null
        }
    },
    receiving() {
        this.setState({
            received: true,
            arr: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        });
    },
    sorting(type) {
        var self = this;
        return function() {
            function sort_func() {
                //sorting...
            }
            var main_arr = self.state.arr;
            main_arr.sort(sort_func);
            self.setState({
                arr: main_arr
            })
        }
    },
    render() {
        if(this.state.received) {
            var all_elems = [];
            this.state.arr.forEach(function(elem) {
                all_elems.push(<Elem name={elem}>);
            });
            return <div>
                <button onClick={this.sorting}>Sort</button>
                {all_elem}
            </div>
        }
        else {
            this.receiving();
            return <div>Empty</div>;
        }
    }
});
```

For example, array after sorting is [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]. At first HTML page is

```
<div>1</div><div>2</div>...<div>5</div>;
```

But after sorting HTML page remained the same, although array in state was changed.

Comment: Give your elements a unique `key` property. Avoid copying prop to state unless you need to modify it (`props.name` => `state.name`)

Comment: Looks like you're using __ES6__! Please use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead of `self = this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done refactoring of your code, because in your version there are couple mistakes

1. In `Elem` you don't need use `state`,
2. Instead of using `this.receiving();` you can add initial data to `arr` in `getInitialState` and avoid use `if`/`else` in `render` method
3. Instead of using `this.state.arr.forEach`  more suitable use `.map
4. Instead of `var self = this;` use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

   ```
   var Elem = React.createClass({
     render() {
       return <div>{ this.props.name }</div>;
     }
   });

   var List = React.createClass({
     getInitialState() {
       return {
         received: false,
         arr: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
       }
     },

     sorting(type) {
       this.setState({
         received: !this.state.received,
         arr: this.state.arr.sort((a, b) => {
           return !this.state.received ? b - a : a - b;
         })
       })
     },

     render() {
       var elements = this.state.arr.map((elem, index) => {
         return <Elem name={elem} key={index} />
       });

       return <div>
         <button onClick={this.sorting}>Sort</button>
         { elements }
       </div>;
     }
   });
   ```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/29546/)